# Using transitionToRoute with a model with a custom slug

Tags: ember.js

I've got an ember-data model that has an `id` as well as a server-generated custom `slug` attribute (which is prefixed with the `id` if that matters).

I'd like to use the `slug` instead of the `id` in all public routres. For that purpose, I have changed the router:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'strategies', path: '/strategies', ->
    @resource 'strategy', path: ':strategy_slug'
```

and overwrote the `serialize` method of the respective route:

```
App.StrategyRoute = Ember.Route.extend()
  serialize: (model) ->
    {
      strategy_slug: model.get('slug')
    }
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work when using transitionToRoute from a controller to transition to, e.g., `/strategies/123-test`:

```
App.ExampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend()

  [...]

  actions:
    showDetails: ->
      @transitionToRoute("/strategies/#{@get('slug')}")
      false
```

(where `@get('slug')` returns `'123-test'`)

All output I get in the console after invoking the `showDetails` action is:

```
Transitioned into 'strategies.index'
```

Ember does seem to recognize the slug-based route.

```
Ember: 1.5.0-beta.2+pre.3ce8f9ac
Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.6
```

Is there anything I may have missed?

**Edit:**

The following variant works and is feasible in this case, but I have another use-case where I have only access to the URL.

```
App.ExampleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend()

  [...]

  actions:
    showDetails: ->
      @transitionToRoute('strategy', @get('content'))
      false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out how to solve this. The key is to add a `model` method to the router, which knows how to turn a slug into a model:

```
App.StrategyRoute = Ember.Route.extend()
  model: (params, transition) ->
    App.store.getById('strategy', parseInt(params.strategy_slug))

  serialize: (model) ->
    {
      strategy_slug: model.get('slug')
    }
```